# Wait for Subject callback to execute

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Consider the following code:

```
const mA = async () => {
    try {
        const subscription = myEmitter.subscribe(url => getD(url));
        const la=()=>{...};
        return la;
    }
     catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

How may I ensure code below `const subscription` runs after `getD` finishes execution?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  `getD` will not execute until a message is sent to the subscription.

Comment: without more info, it's not exactly easy to tell what's happening. Does the callback that you pass to `subscribe` already run before `const la=` runs? is `getD` asyncronous?

Comment: you won t  be able to achieve it, once you execute mA it wil ljust wait for a signal so that subscribe can react to it. the code below subscribe will run immediately upon invoking the mA function if getD is a promise you can await it in the subscribtion and then execute the la function

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit obscure, but I think I understood your intentions.

First, you must be sure that `myEmitter` is finite, means it's not going to run forever.
For example, if `myEmitter = interval(1000)` subscribing to it will never complete, thus you can't run anything "after" it.

Assuming `myEmitter` is finite, you cam simply use `Observable.toPromise` method, since your code already runs in an `async` function, your code will be:

```js
const mA = async () => {
    try {
        const url = myEmitter.toPromise();
        getD(url); // you might need to await this as well
        const la=()=>{...};
        return la;
    }
     catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

**Note:** `toPromise` is being deprecated, you can read more about it in [this blogpost](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/).